# How to make sure a game object is NOT generated on top of any other object

Tags: phaser-framework, matter.js

I'm creating an HTML5 game with Phaser 3 using the Matter.js physics engine. The game has several objects on screen at once, including:

- Instances of a subclass of https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Matter.Image.html
- Instances of a subclass of (animated game object): https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Matter.Sprite.html
- Objects of the following: https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/MatterJS.Body.html

If it matters, the MatterJS.Body objects were generated using `fromVertices()` (documentation here: https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Matter.Factory.html#fromVertices__anchor)

I wish to generate a new `Phaser.Physics.Matter.Image` object with a randomized starting position, however, *this position CANNOT overlap any of the game objects that are already on screen.*

I know how to generate a random coordinate for the object's position. My question is, **how do I check that none of the existing objects contain this coordinate?**

I can get a list of all existing game objects with `this.matter.world.localWorld.bodies)`, so what I've tried is:

1. Generate a random `x` and `y` coordinate.
2. Iterate through `this.matter.world.localWorld.bodies`, and for each game object (let's call it `gameObject`):
3. Call `getBounds().contains(x, y)` to check if the boundaries contain the coordinate.

This actually works when all I have are Images and Sprites, however, I also have MatterJS.Body objects which do not have a `getBounds()` method. That's my main problem. *Edit: They do have a `bounds` attribute but it's just two coordinates labelled min and max, and has no `contains()` method. AABB bounds checking is not sufficient for my goals; I need something more precise.*

Note: I have also thought about simply placing the object on the screen and listening for a collision event. However, it looks like collision events only fire when the collision is triggered by an object in motion, and ideally I would not want to render it at all if it's going to be on top of something.

Final note: I'm open to creating some sort of shape or game object instead of using x and y coordinates if it means an easier way to do what I want to do.